# Having autotools targets being built by WAF

Tags: autotools, waf

We're trying to incrementally move away from autotools to WAF.
Most of our sub-projects are autotools and we don't really want to convert them to WAF at once.

Do you have any tips or things to keep in mind when mixing up WAF and autotools.

I was thinking creating a simple wscript in each autotools subproject that would basically just do shell commands './configure', 'make', 'make install'.
I couldn't find any better solution in WAF example directory. So I was wondering if you guys had any better idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like that with old part of my build that was make-driven. I wrote a simple waf tool that call ./configure && make && make install.

To make it waflike, there is one or two things to do :

- set correctly the inputs of your tasks to rebuild your subdirectory only if something change.
- call configure with parameters in order to build in waf build directory

Answer (score 0):

Something called autowaf exists, but beyond that I am not aware of any documentation (and it is also 2 years old):

http://lv2plug.in/trac/browser/trunk/autowaf.py?rev=2